# form_for and confirm option and passing Rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, formtastic

I have my form

```
= semantic_form_for @order_refund, url: create_partial_refund_order_path do |f|
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :order_id, as: :hidden
    = f.input :amount, label: 'Amount to refund'
  = f.actions :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to create a partial refund?
```

And my spec

```
  it 'performs a partial refund' do
    visit order_path(@order)
    click_link('Partial Refund')
    fill_in('Amount to refund', with: 5)
    save_and_open_page
    click_button('Create Refund')
    current_path.should == order_path(@order)
    page.should have_content 'Partial refund successful.'
  end
```

Why is the test passing when it is not confirming the action?  Thank you!'

Answer (score 0):

The confirmation is made with JavaScript. While your test doesn't use JS than it just doesn't care about it.
If you want to test it than:

1. add to the Gemfile

   `gem 'selenium-webdriver'`
2. enable JS for the test:

   `it 'performs a partial refund', js: true do`